# Group Assignment Codechef

Tags: java, arrays, double-pointer

I was trying out this problem named Group Assignment on CodeChef https://www.codechef.com/START31D/problems/GROUPASSGN

where the problem says

Chef's professor is planning to give his class a group assignment. There are 2N students in the class, with distinct roll numbers ranging from 1 to 2N. Chef's roll number is X.

The professor decided to create N groups of 2 students each. The groups were created as follows: the first group consists of roll numbers 1 and 2N, the second group of roll numbers 2 and 2N−1, and so on, with the final group consisting of roll numbers N and N+1.

Chef wonders who his partner will be. Can you help Chef by telling him the roll number of his partner?

```
EXAMPLE:
3
2 2
3 1
3 4

OUTPUT:
3
6
3
```

My code for the above problem is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;


class Codechef
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        // your code goes here
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=t;i++)
        {
            int m=sc.nextInt();
            int X=sc.nextInt();
            int N=2*m;
            int ar[]=new int[N];
            int start=0;
            int end=ar.length-1;
            for(int j=0;j<N;j++)
            {
                ar[j]=j+1;
            }
            while(start<=end)
            {
                if(ar[start]==X)
                {
                    System.out.println(ar[end]);
                    break;
                }
                else if(ar[end]==X)
                {
                    System.out.println(ar[start]);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    start++;
                    end--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

where I'm getting one test case wrong which is invisible. Can someone help me with the solution?

Comment: I do not believe this task requires any loops.

Comment: I know there is a formula for the question. But what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: `int ar[]=new int[N];` Maybe you run out of memory for large `N`? You can do it without the array. `for (int start=1, end=2*m; start < end; start++, end--) {...}` Or use the method in the first comment.

Comment: Are you guaranteed that `X` is between `1` and `2N`?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp for (int start=1, end=2*m; start < end; start++, end--) {...} still getting TLE.